Rendering PDF Jetpack Compose
I am trying to download a pdf from URL and display it via PDF Renderer in Jetpack Compose. I use the following code:
@Composable
actual fun openFile(url: String): Boolean {
var display by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

val file = File.createTempFile("file", ".pdf")
file.deleteOnExit()
LaunchedEffect(true) {
    val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val body = client.newCall(request).execute().body()
        println(body.contentType())
        body.bytes()
    }
    file.writeBytes(response)

    display = true
}

if (display) {
    val parcelFileDescriptor =
        ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
    val pdfRenderer: PdfRenderer
    try {
        pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e)
        return false
    }
    val pages = mutableListOf<ImageBitmap>()
    for (i in 0 until pdfRenderer.pageCount) {
        val page = pdfRenderer.openPage(i)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.width, page.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
        pages.add(bitmap.asImageBitmap())
        page.close()
    }
    pdfRenderer.close()
    parcelFileDescriptor.close()
    file.delete()

    LazyColumn {
        pages.forEach { image ->
            item {
                Image(
                    bitmap = image,
                    contentDescription = "PDF page"
                )
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    CircularProgressIndicator(color = Color.White)
}
return true
}

But I keep getting an IOException that the file is invalid despite the fact that file extension is .pdf and body.contentType() also prints "application/pdf".
Can anyone help me resolve the issue?
Example URL that app loads: https://accorm.ginastic.co/200/IGCSE/accounting/QP/0452_w23_qp_11.pdf

Well...3rd party libraries seemed a better option, so I switched to
https://github.com/GRizzi91/bouquet io.github.grizzi91:bouquet

Also I found out that removing the line file.deleteOnExit() fixed it. Seems like file was deleted a little too early.
